# Property binding in MVVM

Tags: c#-4.0, binding

my cpde in ModelView :

```
 public Boolean EnableTextBox { get; set; }

 public CustomerAccountVM()
 {

     this.EnableTextBox = false;

      //...
 }
```

code in View:
XAML :

```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IdCustomer, Mode=Default}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableTextBox,Mode=Default}" />
```

**Why the code does not work?**

no answer ?

Comment: You need to tell us more about what's its doing and what it's supposed to.

Comment: I want to in ModelView the textbox to enable or disable.

Answer (score 0):

You're not publishing the fact that the Enable property has been updated.

You need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and change your property to be:

```
private Boolean _enableTextBox;
public Boolean EnableTextBox
{
    get { return _enableTextBox; }
    set
    {
        _enableTextBox = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
 }
```

You should wrap the `PropertyChanged` code in a method so you're not repeating yourself.